# how to load multi textures for one model in ursina Python

Tags: python, ursina

I need to load 3 texture for a house in my `ursina` game

My code:

```
textures = ["wall","slap","window"]

class Homes(Button):
    def __init__(self,pos = (10,1,0)):
       super().__init__(
          parent = scene,
          model = 'images/house',
          texture = textures,
          scale = (5,12,5),
          position = pos,
          color = color.lime,
          origin_y = 0.5,
        )

home = Homes()
```

Comment: Hi @proking, as per the recommended guidelines in stack overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), could you please inform us of what you have already attempted and flesh out your question into full sentences?

Comment: To apply multiple textures to a model, you'll have to bake (combine) them together and use UV mapping for the arrangement. This can be done e.g. in Blender.

Answer (score -2):

```
texture1=load_texture("tx1.png")

texture2=load_texture("tx2.png")

#and another texture

md1 = Entity(model="your model", texture=[texture1, texture2])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This answer is just wrong.